# How do we index through an input array to a lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

I am pretty new to lambda expressions and am trying to write a simple program here to understand the use of `Func<>` and can't understand why I cannot loop through an input array using indexing?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] array = new int[4];
        array[0] = -1; array[1] = 2; array[2] = 3; array[3] = 8;

        Func<Array, int> DoSomething = inputarray =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < inputarray.Length; i++)
            {
                if (inputarray[i] > inputarray[i + 1])
                {
                    //;
                }

            }
            return 1;
        };

    }
}
```

This gives an error saying

> cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type Array

How do I resolve this? Basically, how would I loop through my input array?

Comment: Change Array in Func<> to int[] or do you van to have an option that it will except all kinds of arrays

Comment: Works..!!! But what was wrong with type Array?? Is it because arrays do not have indexers?? idk

Comment: I think `Array` refers to `System.Array` which is not exactly an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`System.Array`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array(v=vs.110).aspx) is the base class of all arrays like an `int[]`. It implements also `IList` which allows to access items by index, but the [`Item` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb494734(v=vs.110).aspx) is implemented as an explicit interface member implementation. It can be used only when the `Array` instance is cast to an `IList` interface:

```
var list = (System.Collections.IList)inputarray;
```

Now you can use the indexer but it will return objects not ints, so you can't use following without casting because objects can't be compared with `>`:

```
if (list[i] > list[i + 1])
{
    //;
}
```

I guess you want to use an `int[]`:

```
Func<int[], int> DoSomething = inputarray =>
// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a type for the Array in the example you show.

try:

```
Func<int[], int> DoSomething
```

instead.